# How to enable an ASP.NET MVC web app using Forms Authentication as a SAML SSO ID Provider?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml, intercom

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application on .NET 4.5. The application is using forms authentication. We want this application to act as an ID Provider for a SSO integration with [Intercom](https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/3974587-integrate-with-an-identity-provider-and-log-in-with-saml-sso).

Does .NET 4.5 have any built in functionality to enable this via configuration? Or would I need to build out something custom to make this work?

If the later, can someone suggest a framework or open source implementation that could get me started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't include any built in SAML SSO functionality.

There is an open source implementation from Sustainsys. Alternatively, you could use the commercial product available from us.